# How to handle download file save dialog in firefox through protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, cross-browser, automated-tests

I'm having a problem running a protractor test. Test has to download a file which is facing a popup in firefox as shown below:

[image]

Can someone please help me how to avoid this on firefox?

I'm using protractor: 5.4.1, NodeJS: 8.11.2

My conf.js Capabilities:
capabilities: {
     'browserName': 'firefox',
     'marionette' : true,
     'shardTestFiles': true,
     'maxInstances': 1,
     "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "application/zip"
   },

Note: Chrome doesn't have this so it's working fine there.

Regards,
Naresh Surya

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
export let config: Config = {
seleniumAddress: '...',
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            prefs: {
                'browser.download.folderList' : 2,
                'browser.download.dir' : downloadsPath,
                'services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir' : true,
                'browser.download.useDownloadDir' : true,
                'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone':true,
                'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false, 
                'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force':false,
                'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete':false,
                'browser.download.manager.useWindow':false,
                'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/pdf,application/csv,text/plain,application/vnd.csv',
                'pdfjs.disabled': true
            },
        }
...
```

Being dowloadsPath your variable with the path where you want it to save.

If it does not work for you, you can always try with many other types like:

```
application/xml,text/plain,text/comma-separat‌​ed-values,application/excel,application/octet-stream,application/xlsx,application/xls,aplication/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,text/xml,application/csv,application/pdf,application/octet-stream,application/x-winzip,,application/x-gzip
```

If you have a way to prevent firefox opening the file .xml or csv, just let me know. So far, mine is only working for pdf.

Here you have more info: 
[http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:*FAQs*:_About:config_Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries)